# Error while configuring NGINX for multiple subdomains

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to configure my NGINX to handle requests from two different subdomains routing them to two different nodeJS apps running on ports 3000 and 9000. I'm also routing all port 80 requests to 443. Here's what my config looks like:

```
# Catch non-ssl domain requests
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name schandillia.com www.schandillia.com;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

# Catch non-www domain requests on ssl
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name  schandillia.com;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

# Settings for TLS enabled server (www/ssl requests)
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name  www.schandillia.com;

  # Retrieve certificates
  ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/schandillia.com/fullchain.pem";
  ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/schandillia.com/privkey.pem";

  # Automatically route HTTP to HTTPS
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

  include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
  add_header X-Powered-By "Project Proost 0.0.0";
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    charset UTF-8;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
  location ~* \.(?:ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   expires 365d;
   add_header Pragma public;
   add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
}

# for subdomain graph 
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name graph.schandillia.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

As evident, there's 4 server blocks in my configuration. The first handles all non-SSL requests, the second routes non-WWW SSL requests to WWW, and the third handles all requests to https://www.schandillia.com, routing them to port 3000.

The 4th block is where I am handling requests from the subdomain, graph.schandillia.com and attempting to route them to port 9000. This however throws an error with no error code:

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code.

Where am I going wrong?

P.S.: `nginx -t` returns the following log:

```
nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:56
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Also, the configuration seems to work fine with the last server block removed. But that doesn't serve my purpose as I do need a server block to handle the `graph` subdomain requests.

Comment: what does nginx -t say about your config syntax?

Comment: @Rob: Updated question with `nginx -t` response.

Comment: As the error log says, you have designated two different servers as default_server. There can be only one default per protocol, kind of like The Highlander (without the soundtrack).